# how to make an intersection between a shapefile and A WMS layer in QGIS 2.8.1

Tags: qgis, intersection, qgis-2.8

I am using QGIS 2.8.1

I think what I want to do is an intersection between a shapefile and A WMS layer, both in vector format.

I have 1 small vector layer that consists of different forest stands, identified by a number.
I want to combine this with WMS-layers, for example this one from https://www.dov.vlaanderen.be/geoserver/dov-pub-bodem/bodemtypes/wms? , that contains information about soil types.

What I want is a table that contains for each forest stand the corresponding information from the WMS layers, for example the soil type.
It is possible that 1 forest stand contains 2 soil types, then I have to know the proportion of the area of each soil type compared to the size of the forest stand. 
It would be even better if the result was a new shapefile, similar as my original shapefile, that contains the information about the soil type and that showed where a forest stand consists of different soil types. (from this I can directly make the table I mentioned above)

This is different from a "spatial query" because I am not looking for a specific soil type.

Comment: WMS service is sending you just an image. If the WMS layer of the soil types is classified you could calculate how many pixels of all distinct RGB values fall inside your polygons and build your table. But luckily that server supports also WFS and you can get the soil type date as true vectors https://www.dov.vlaanderen.be/geoserver/dov-pub-bodem/bodemtypes/wfs?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetCapabilities.

Comment: Thanks! But how do I do that? (getting the soil type date as true vectors)

Comment: I suggest to read first the WFS section of the QGIS manual.

Comment: It would be better if you can get access to the data you need as **WFS** instead of WMS. WMS will just provide a georeferenced "image". A WFS will provide you with feature information (attributes), which is what you need to perform your desired task. Maybe this page is helpful understanding the difference if you are new to it [Overview: WMS, WFS, WCS](http://www.geowebguru.com/2009/02/09/overview-wms-wfs-wcs/).

Comment: @user30184 and Chris, Thanks for explaining the difference between WFS and WMS. It works fine now for the WFS layer. But The problem is that the information I need is for some reason not in the WFS layer only in the WMS layer. So how do I calculate how many pixels of all distinct RGB values fall inside each polygon?